# Have multiple aggregations in a query always the same order?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Im asking for PostgreSQL specifically, but answers for other popular SQL implementations are appreciated as well.

Given an sql query with multiple aggregates, especially `array_agg`, is the order of the aggregated values deterministic?

Example:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(columnA), ARRAY_AGG(columnB) FROM myTable
GROUP BY columnC
```

Can I rely on both arrays to have the same order, meaning values at position **i** in both arrays will belong to the same source row?

I can't find anything about this in the docs and I'm unsure because I've read that parallelization could be used in calculating aggregates, which I'm afraid could possibly result in non-deterministic orders.

Comment: How hard did you look? [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html): "The aggregate functions array_agg, json_agg, jsonb_agg, json_object_agg, jsonb_object_agg, string_agg, and xmlagg, as well as similar user-defined aggregate functions, produce meaningfully different result values depending on the order of the input values. This ordering is unspecified by default, but can be controlled by writing an ORDER BY clause within the aggregate call"

Comment: In the case you give, all the aggregates will happen to be in sync with each other, just because making them not be in sync would take more work than having them be in sync and PostgreSQL tries to do things with less work.  But you should not rely on this.  I don't know what might cause this to change in some future version, but it could change.

Comment: @Damien This states that the overall order in which the rows are aggregated is arbitrary, which is clear because the order of the returned rows is not deterministic. My question is, if this arbitrary order is at least "in snync" ,as jjanes puts it, over all aggregates in a single query. If the database uses parallelization to up the performance of aggregate calculation, this might not be the case

Comment: The conclusion, *as always*, is if you want *an* ordering you can rely on, you have the tools available to ask for it by using `ORDER BY`. Otherwise, it's *arbitrary*, and you shouldn't expect any guarantees.

Comment: I agree. As a safety measure I will continue to do so. I was hoping to simplify things a bit when there exists such an inherent order-determinism..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order is never deterministic if you don't provide an `order by`

So if you need a specific order, then specify it:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(columnA order by some_sort_column), 
       ARRAY_AGG(columnB order by some_sort_column) 
FROM myTable
GROUP BY columnC
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why people here didn't understand the question and all of them quote the documentation incorrectly, by providing correct answer, but for different question.

Yes, both aggregate functions are called on the same row, at the same time, and this is guided by the query parser.

If you don't believe or trust it you can do something better that doing the sorting:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(CONCAT(myTable.ctid, ':', columnA)),
       ARRAY_AGG(CONCAT(myTable.ctid, ':', columnB))
FROM myTable
GROUP BY columnC
```

now you'll see that both result aggregates having the same ctid on both sides, for each element of the array, simply because both are called at the same time and there is no way around for PG to do something else.

Assuming that is not enough to convince you, then you have no other choice but to refactor your original query like this:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(ARRAY[columnA, columnB])
FROM myTable
GROUP BY columnC
```

Now you have what you want: columnA and columnB together!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you link any sources that document your statement that "both aggregate functions are called on the same row, at the same time, and this is guided by the query parser." ? I agree with you that the behavior is testable with example queries, yet I would like to understand the mechanics better e.g. by reading the corresponding part in the official docs - thanks

Comment: @asturm when I talk about the parser - if does not work like this then it won't be possible to do simple math operations like max(columnA) - max(columnB) when the result is based on window function (i.e. taking just first n rows), because now both functions will be evaluated on different set of rows. It is not a single documentation line, where you'll read exactly for your case.

However, if you need proof - there is a test in the pg code base: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/test/regress/expected/arrays.out

Search for this:

SELECT array_agg(x) || array_agg(x)

Comment: @asturm and to anticipate your next question: if array_agg(x) can produce different result because is not guaranteed the order of rows execution, then the parser cannot optimize the call to array_agg(x) and will need to do two separate calls to array_agg(x) || array_agg(x) although they have the same argument (column x). Thus, the test above will pass only if it is guaranteed that both calls are done in the same order. Compare it to this:

`SELECT array_agg(x order by x desc) || array_agg(x) FROM (VALUES (ROW(1,2)), (ROW(3,4))) v(x)`